# How to use custom express server with sveltekit in dev

Tags: node.js, express, sveltekit

I was able to set up a custom express server in sveltekit, but it only works in build with adapter node. How can I use it in dev?

I can't find anything useful on google.

Comment: In dev, Vite provides *its own server*, so what exactly do you mean by using a custom one? If you mean to combine the functions of the two servers, check out the [backend integration docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/backend-integration.html#backend-integration).

Comment: For example if I have a websocket server running on express. How can I keep the functionality in dev.

Comment: Do you have a repo with your custom express + sveltekit server? I'm trying to do the same and really struggling. Also did you ever figure this out?